software for computing with Lie algebra representations
I would like to explore irreducible modules over the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbf{C})$ with the help of a computer.
What is the best software for this?
Concretely, I am interested in plotting weight diagrams for the case $n=3$ for various highest weights and inspecting dimensions of weight spaces.

Fulton and Harris have already plotted this in their book. The is a CAS called "Lie".

I have found this package very useful for Dynkin diagram computations and visualizations of root systems. It can be used to compute highest weight representations, though I have no experience with this capability.
